# eJabber XMPP chat sample

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

I want to integrate XMPP chat using eJabber server.

I have tried many samples which are not working and some open source app I have checked

https://github.com/guardianproject/ChatSecureAndroid

https://github.com/redsolution/xabber-android

etc.

But its not easy to modify, so do you have any simple example so it will easy to modify?

Comment: what issue you facing , did u create any demo for this ?

Comment: From the official close reasons: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._